# Problema con IF en C mi código no funciona como debería

Tags: c

Hola quede atascado en este código no se me ocurre como hacer que funcione:

```
int main(void) {
    int n1,n2;

    printf("Ingrese el primer numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n1);

    printf("\nIngrese el segundo numero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n2);

    if (n1 > n2) printf("\nEl primer numero es el mayor\n");
    if (n2 < n1) printf("\nEl segundo numero es el mayor\n");
}
```

Como pueden ver es muy simple pero no le encuentro el error :c

Comment: ¿Algún error al compilar o al ejecutar?¿Qué valores entras para n1 y n2?¿Falla siempre o sólo con algunos valores?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Muy simple, ambos if evalúan la misma condición, observa que inviertes el operador y el orden de las variables, por lo tanto no hay diferencia.

Utiliza en cambio:

```
if (n1 > n2) printf("\nEl primer numero es el mayor\n");
if (n2 > n1) printf("\nEl segundo numero es el mayor\n");
```

En tu ejemplo tal cual, si utilizas un numero mas alto primero, veras que imprime los dos mensajes.

Comment: @CristoferFuentes Por favor, modérese, no se permiten críticas autodestructivas, que no pase la próxima.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas cristofer, quizás llegue un poco tarde, pero allá va mi respuesta: salvo por pequeñas correcciones, el problema principal que tiene este código sería en parte a lo que dice md, está comprobando 2 veces una condición, algo que sería innecesario, y que puede acarrearte más de un quebradero de cabeza como el que te has topado con este código. En cambio, prueba aplicar una estructura selectiva doble (if/else), sólo existen dos resultados a este algoritmo, por lo que le va como anillo al dedo.

No sólo solventas el problema principal, sino que mejora el rendimiento del algoritmo al usar una estructura más adecuada, ahorrando tiempo y recursos, algo muy valorado en el campo de la informática tanto como la creación misma del programa. Saludos

Comment: Se q llego tarde con el comentario, pero hay un tercer resultado que se da cuando ambos numeros son iguales. Utilizando `if/else` en caso de igualdad funcionaria diferente la forma actual con los dos `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un `else`, en lugar de preguntar de nuevo. Quedaría así

```
if (n1 > n2)
   printf("\nEl primer numero es el mayor\n");
else
   printf("\nEl segundo numero es el mayor\n");
```

Edito:
 Si quieres comprobar si los números son iguales puedes hacer algo como esto

```
if (n1 > n2)
    printf("\nEl primer numero es el mayor\n");
else if (n1 == n2)
    printf("\nLos numeros son iguales\n");
else
    printf("\nEl segundo numero es el mayor\n");
```

Answer (score -2):

Lo que te falto fueron los corchetes
Con esto ya te funciona

```
if(n1 > n2){printf("\nEl primer numero es el mayor\n");}
if(n2 > n1){printf("\nEl segundo numero es el mayor\n");}
```

Comment: No son corchetes, sino, llaves. En este caso no necesitas llaves porque solo es una instrucción, si fueran más de uno, ahí si.